# Nhibernate inheritance mapping mixing Type-Per-Hierarchy with Type-Per-Class?

Tags: c#, nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping

I'm trying to map this classes:

```
public interface IBusinessObject
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}
public class Product
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
}
public class ProductWeSell : Product, IBusinessObject
{
}
public class ProductWeDontSell : Product
{
}
```

To database with 2 tables:

```
[BusinessObject] COLUMNS ([Id])
[Product] COLUMNS ([Id], [ProdyctTypeId])
```

I want to have Type-Per-Class for BusinessObject, and Type-Per-Hierarchy with Product. This should result in this behavior:

- Add Product : INSERT INTO Product {Guid), null}
- Add ProductWeDontSell : INSERT INTO Product {Guid, 2}
- Add ProductWeSell: INSERT INTO BusinessObject {Guid}; INSERT INTO Product {SameGuid, 1}

Logically hbm mappings should be:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" name="IBusinessObject" table="BusinessObject">
    <joined-subclass name="ProductWeSell" table="Product"/>
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>

<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" discriminator-value="null" name="Product" table="Product">
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="ProductTypeId" not-null="false" />
    </discriminator>
    <subclass name="ProductWeDontSell" discriminator-value="2" />
    <subclass name="ProductWeSell" discriminator-value="1" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

But I get {"Duplicate class/entity mapping ProductWeSell"} error.

Comment: Just learning this myself, have you looking into all that you can do with IMappingOverride? http://wiki.fluentnhibernate.org/Auto_mapping

Comment: @kenny, No, i have neve heard of IMappingOverride, but i know there is IAutoMappingOverride, but i don't use auto-mapping.

Comment: Yeah my bad, IAutoMappingOverride. Good luck.

Comment: I don't think you can mix inheritance strategies like this.  Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2715701/mixing-inheritance-mapping-strategies-in-nhibernate

Comment: Another place to look which may shed some light on the issue is: http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2011/02/16/get-load-polymorphism-in-nhibernate-3.aspx .  I'm thinking you're going to have to do this with either an abstract base class or not at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came to interesting conclusion. I decided to change my architecture and use separate classes for data access layer, and domain-UI layer, I just convert my objects when they cross the layer. Any way it is a good practice to have decoupled data-access and UI. So my data-access model now is pretty plain without any inheritance, inheritance appear only at domain-UI level.

Answer (score 1):

I'm fairly certain that with Fluent NHibernate this can not be done.  I created the following TestFixture while i was trying to come up with a way.  Also I'm not sure what you are trying to map.  IBusinessObject seems redundant if you're going to use it for every entity in the system (CreateQuery("from object") will return every entity inheriting from object i.e. everything)

Note: Currently this fails on the IBusinessObject query (as it should as it isn't mapped).  I'm not quite sure why this doesn't work without mapping the IBusinessObject interface as implicit polymorphism seems like it should cover this (See: http://nhibernate.info/doc/nh/en/index.html#inheritace-mixingpolymorphism).

```
[TestFixture]
public class TestFixture
{

    private ISessionFactory _sessionFactory;
    private ISession _session;
    [SetUp]
    public void Setup()
    {
        var fluentConfig = Fluently.Configure().Database(() => SQLiteConfiguration.Standard.InMemory().Provider<TestConnectionProvider>())
                                   .Mappings(x=>x.FluentMappings.Add<ProductMap>()
                                                                .Add<ProductWeSellMap>()
                                                                .Add<ProductWeDontSellMap>());
        var nhConfig = fluentConfig.BuildConfiguration();
        _sessionFactory = fluentConfig.BuildSessionFactory();

        var schema = new SchemaExport(nhConfig);
        schema.Execute(false, true, false);

        _session = _sessionFactory.OpenSession();
    }

    [Test]
    public void SomeTest()
    {
        using (var itx = this._session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            var productSold = new ProductWeSell();
            var productNotSold = new ProductWeDontSell();
            _session.Save(productNotSold);
            _session.Save(productSold);
            itx.Commit();
        }

        using (var itx = this._session.BeginTransaction())
        {
            Assert.That(_session.CreateQuery("from ProductWeSell").List(), Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
            Assert.That(_session.CreateQuery("from ProductWeDontSell").List(), Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
            Assert.That(_session.CreateQuery("from IBusinessObject").List(), Has.Count.EqualTo(1));
            Assert.That(_session.CreateQuery("from Product").List(), Has.Count.EqualTo(2));
        }
    }
}

public interface IBusinessObject
{
    Guid Id { get; set; }
}

public class Product
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; set; }
    public virtual int ProductTypeId { get; set; }
}
public class ProductMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    public ProductMap()
    {
        this.Id(x => x.Id);
        this.DiscriminateSubClassesOnColumn("ProductTypeId");
    }
}

public class ProductWeSell : Product, IBusinessObject
{
    public const int ProductWeSellTypeId = 1;
}

public class ProductWeSellMap : SubclassMap<ProductWeSell>
{
    public ProductWeSellMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue(ProductWeSell.ProductWeSellTypeId);
    }
}

public class ProductWeDontSell : Product
{
    public const int ProductWeDontSellTypeId = 2;
}

public class ProductWeDontSellMap : SubclassMap<ProductWeDontSell>
{
    public ProductWeDontSellMap()
    {
        this.DiscriminatorValue(ProductWeDontSell.ProductWeDontSellTypeId);
    }
}
```

This produces the following HBM mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" default-access="property" auto-import="true" default-cascade="none" default-lazy="true">
  <class xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2" mutable="true" name="CellTester.Test.Database.Product, Test, Version=2.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a15dc1b99998d28b" table="`Product`">
    <id name="Id" type="System.Guid, mscorlib, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089">
      <column name="Id" />
      <generator class="guid.comb" />
    </id>
    <discriminator type="String">
      <column name="ProductTypeId" />
    </discriminator>
    <subclass name="ProductWeSell, Test, Version=2.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a15dc1b99998d28b" discriminator-value="1" />
    <subclass name="ProductWeDontSell, Test, Version=2.0.0.3, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=a15dc1b99998d28b" discriminator-value="2" />
  </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Comment: @Nicholas : Quote " IBusinessObject seems redundant if you're going to use it for every entity in the system ". I'm not going to use with every entity, that's exactly why I need this. Take a look at ProductWeDontSell : Product - It's product but not IBusinessObject.

Comment: @Broken Pipe:  Ok.  What are you trying to do with IBusinessObject?  Why is it there? (I know you've created a toy example to post)  How do you want to use it in a query?  Right now you could just do "from ProductWeSell" and it would be equivalent to the (as of now not working "from IBusinessObject").

Comment: @Nicholas:I was planing to use IBusinessObject, to get all Products, that implement this interface in short. Or more deeper the idea was, to use it to flag that some objects are important on their own, and some are just part of other bigger object graph. I want to use I BusinessObject as a pointer to aggregate root (object graph root). Wait i'l try to explain this better )

Comment: @Broken Pipe: It will be FAR easier to use an abstract base class for each root than an interface. From all the googling I've done trying to find if this was even possible it seems that A) The author of FNH doesn't really like this implementation (see: http://tinyurl.com/5tf6lxc) and B) FNH seems to be lacking in the support of interfaces. You could hack this out with HBMs or alternatively try to fix FNH (around FNH.Visitors.SeparateSubclassVisitor.DistanceFromParentBase)

Comment: @Nicholas: I agree, that it will be easer to use abstract class, but I need multiple inheritance, and C# support only multiple interface inheritance. I really want to have have all my "products" derive from Product class, and some of them derive from other class (interface). It's pretty easy to do at database level, and i have working database, I can query it easily as I need using plain SQL, but can't map this to Nhibernate. Besides I have just read on NH mailing list that you can't query over interfaces, not sure if it's true.

Comment: @Nicholas: I saw that posts, i was googling for like 6 hours for solution to this problem without any luck, looks like I will have to abandon this idea, and thinking on using Table per class hierarchy with some hacks.

Comment: @Broken Pipe: I'm using table per class in a project.  It works great you just need to be careful to not have too many subclasses (with collections in them) or you can end up with really nasty Cartesian products.  Also querying over an interface is definitely supported (Take a look at the nh docs theres an example that queries using an IPayment to implicitly refer to all payment types which implement IPayment)  Also all Product's deriving from product would work as long as you don't need to do have one Product inherit from two other Product implementors.